# F6 shortcut does not work on IntelliJ IDEA and MacOS X?

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

By default on IntelliJ IDEA, the <kbd>F6</kbd> key is used for the `Move` refactoring action.

However on my MacOS X, hitting F6 does not have any result. Going to the `Keymap` settings I can see that the `Move` action is indeed assigned to <kbd>F6</kbd>.

I tried to remove the assignment and recreate it, but when I try to type the <kbd>F6</kbd> key to configure the assignment it is not picked up by the `Configure key
board shortcut window`. Interestingly, I have the same behavior with <kbd>F5</kbd> but not with the other <kbd>Fx</kbd> keys (<kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>F4</kbd> and <kbd>F7</kbd> to <kbd>F12</kbd>, those I can assign and use as shortcuts).

My guess is that one of my other applications uses <kbd>F5</kbd> and <kbd>F6</kbd> as shortcuts accessible from anywhere and prevents IntelliJ from receiving the events, but how can I detect which application ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally went with the bruteforce way of killing each app one after the other in OSX Activity Monitor until I was able to use the <kbd>F6</kbd> shortcut again.

In my case, the culprit was a small application called MuteMyMic.

Comment: The list of keyboards shortcuts in the system preferences didn't show this? Or CueCat? (I'm asking because I'm trying to unify my shortcuts.)

Comment: The system preferences did not show it, no. No idea about CueCat.

Answer (score 6):

It worked with me:

> [fn + shift + F6]

macbook pro 2015
mac os 10.14.5